# Access SQL Query Equal Row Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing a SQL statement to display the properties of a school course. These properties are **Capacity** and **Enrollment**. I'm trying to create a column that will display *FULL* if `Enrollment = Capacity` and *NOT FULL* if `Enrollment < Capacity`.

### For example:

```
    Capacity      Enrollment 
    10                 9      -----> Not Full
    10                 10     -----> Full
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `Select capacity, enrollment, Case when capacity=enrollment then 'Full' else 'Not Full' end as enrollment_status from my_table`

Comment: You want the `iif()` function.

Comment: @Ravinder - your answer is wrong.  `CASE` does not work in MS-ACCESS, `IFF()` is needed.

Comment: @Hogan: My answer was given when question was tagged under `mysql`

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Classname, iif(Enrollment = Capacity, "Full","Not Full") as ClassStatus from ClassTable;
```

Obviously, you'll need some way to prevent over-enrollment.